# PHP session not working on page refresh

Tags: php, session, logging, authentication

I'm trying to create a mock-up of a site with the ability of logging in using PHP and session.

**menu.php**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">Index</a></li>
    <li><a href="log.php">Log In</a></li>
</ul>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    include("menu.php");

    echo "<br>Main page here<br>";
?>
```

**log.php**

```
<?php
    include("menu.php");

    session_start();

    if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
        $_SESSION['user'] = "Test Login";
        echo "Welcome " . $_SESSION['user'];
    }

    else {
        echo "You are already logged in as: " . $_SESSION['user'];
    }
 ?>
```

My issue is that every time I click the link to `log.php` using `menu.php` I always get the "Welcome Test Login" message, as if the session was resetting every click.

Is there a way to get the "You are already logged in as: Test Login" message from the second click on `log.php` onwards?

Comment: You're re-starting the session in log.php

Comment: You have output before you start your session in log.php

Comment: @snack_overflow I removed `session_start();` from `log.php` but the results are the same

Comment: @JohnConde do you mean the `session_start();` should be above the include in log.php? That doesn't fix the issue either